# Need a strategy for caching information about an object without keeping it alive

Tags: c#, performance, caching

I have a library which processes objects (which happen to be immutable). Many times, it processes the same objects over and over again, but it has no way of knowing, so it does a bunch of repeated work.

A good analogy might be that I'm rendering an interface. My render function returns a frame, but 99% of work that went into rendering that frame is used and thrown away. Much of that work can be re-used if the next time I'm asked to render a frame containing that control, I recognize that it's the same control (just maybe with a slightly different state).

---

If this were real life, and I were dealing with people, I'd give everyone an "id card" to give back to me next time they visit, so that I could look them up in my database if I ever saw them again. Unfortunately, in most programming languages (including C#), you can't just "enhance" arbitrary objects with custom data to more easily identify them later.

I considered keeping a cache of objects I've seen before:

```
Dictionary<Object, ReallyExpensiveInformation> cache = new ...;
```

Or, if we're worried about objects that override "Equals" incorrectly:

```
Dictionary<CachedObject, ReallyExpensiveInformation> cache = new ...;
// Where CachedObject is defined as:
private class CachedObject : IEquatable<CachedObject> {
    Object Value { get; set; }
    // Get the native hash code that is based on the object reference
    override int GetHashCode() => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(Value);
    // Ensure each new reference is processed, even if they would claim to be equivalent
    override bool Equals(CachedObject other) => ReferenceEquals(Value, other.Value);
}
```

These approaches both suffer from the same core problem in my mind, which is that they create a **memory leak** by holding on to objects that might otherwise have been finalized.

I said I encounter the same objects over and over, but I encounter many more that I never see again. I have loads of space for storing `ReallyExpensiveInformation`, because the final result is small, but the `Objects` might be big, and I don't know what ones the caller is holding on to, and what ones they are abandoning to be garbage collected. The caller may or may not be keeping a bunch of references to these objects, but if they decide they're done with them, I don't want my cache to be the things keeping them from being garbage collected.

I almost wish there was some way to hook the "reference count" of an object and dump it once I'm the last holdout.

---

Anyways, my next thought would be to have my own "GarbageCollection" phase. Enhance my dictionary with last-accessed times, and purge any entries that haven't been re-used in a while. That's a complex problem to solve though. I'm wondering if I've completely neglected to think of some simpler solution.

Hopefully it's clear that I'm not in control of the objects I'm processing, otherwise I'd enhance their object model.

Comment: What information are looking to keep? I almost want to say, rip through the object with reflection, get what you need and then use the HashCode as your key.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference?view=netframework-4.7.2 Good for caching. If it is garbage-collected, reload it, if not use it.

Comment: @Eser One day I will remember that exists... hopefully it is the day I need it.  =/

Comment: `WeakReference` looks incredibly useful. Let me see what I can flesh out with this.

Comment: @Eser I took a stab at fleshing out a solution based on that class if you have any further suggestions or gotchas to point out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, @Eser has just turned me on to [`System.WeakReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference?view=netframework-4.7.2). Let's see what this would look like:

```
private class CachedReference : IEquatable<CachedObject> {
    private readonly int _hash;
    public WeakReference Value { get; }
    public CachedReference (Object obj) {
        Value = new WeakReference(obj);
        _hash = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(Value);
    }
    override int GetHashCode() => _hash;
    // If our value is garbage collected, we'll stop matching anything
    override bool Equals(CachedObject other) =>
        Value != null && ReferenceEquals(Value, other.Value);
}

ConcurrentDictionary<CachedReference, ReallyExpensiveInformation> cache = new ...;

// And we use it like this
public ReallyExpensiveInformation GetOrCompute(Object obj) =>
    return cache.GetOrAdd(new CachedReference(obj), key => ComputeExpensiveInfo(key.Value));
```

---

It looks like we're still need some process to "Garbage Collect" dictionary entries that have been left dangling:

- To save on memory consumed by dictionary entries, keys, and cache values
- To keep the size of the Dictionary small / and therefore keep look-ups fast.

Something like this perhaps?

```
Timer garbageCollection = new Timer { AutoReset = true; Interval = 1000 };
Timer.Elapsed += () => cache.Keys.Where(k => k.Value == null)
                                 .ToList().ForAll(k => cache.TryRemove(k, out _));
```

It's kind of gross, and I dislike the thought of periodic **`O(N)`** removals interfering with the cache. (i.e. "Freezing" or slowing access while it's cleaned up or replaced).

Definitely better off than we were, but I wonder if there's anything more elegant that can be done about the cleanup.

Comment: [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of *ConcurrentDictionary* ?